# Faceting with Rubberband

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, facet, rubber-band

I am implementing ElasticSearch in a Ruby-on-Rails 2.3 application with the RubberBand gem. I am trying to return facets but I can't seem to find methods that I can use for this purpose. I've looked through the [documentation and source](https://github.com/grantr/rubberband/tree/master/lib/elasticsearch/client).

Does anyone know if it's possible with rubberband?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue might have what you are looking for:

https://github.com/grantr/rubberband/issues/4

```
q = {
  "query"=> {
    "filtered"=> {
      "query"=> { 
        "match_all"=> {}
      },
      "filter"=> {
        "term"=> {
          "client_id"=> "717",
          "product_id"=> "1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "facets"=> {
    "shipped_to_state_counts"=> {
      "terms"=> {
        "field"=> "state",
        "size"=> "500"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: (simpler query, lucene syntax)

> NOTE: These are not the same queries, per elasticsearch documentation:
>
> There’s one important distinction to keep in mind. While search
>   `queries` restrict both the returned documents and facet counts, search
>   `filters` restrict only returned documents — but not facet counts.

```
q = {
  "query"=> {
    "query_string"=> {
      "query"=> "client_id:717 AND product_id:1"
    }
  },
  "facets"=> {
    "shipped_to_state_counts"=> {
      "terms"=> {
        "field"=> "state",
        "size"=> "500"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**END EDIT**

```
results = client.search(q)
facets = results.facets

=>
{
  "shipped_to_state_counts"=> {
    "_type"=> "terms",
    "missing"=> 0,
    "total"=> 1873274,
    "other"=> 0,
    "terms"=> [
      {
        "term"=> "MO",
        "count"=> 187327
      },
      {
        "term"=> "FL",
        "count"=> 17327
      }
    ]
  }
}
```